# Looping through a list of 5 elements only get result for 1 element

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sorry to ask this seemly simple question. I encountered a strange behavoir where looping through a list of 5 elements only gets result for 1 element.
The code is:

```
    for ac in ac_restriction:
        npa_util += [(ac, IntradayNPARecord.objects.get(category=ac.category)]

    print("Size of npa_util is %i" % len(npa_util))
    print("nap_util is %s" % npa_util)
    for (ac, util) in npa_util:
        print("util.id is %s" % util.id)
        print("ac.category is %s" % ac.category)
        print("util.limit is %s" % util.limit)
```

the output is:

```
Size of npa_util is 5
nap_util is [(<AssetClassRestriction: DRV_248_LE:r>, <IntradayNPARecord: DRV_248_LE:req_SDC223_1611329111171109:2017/12/01>), (<AssetClassRestriction: DRV_248_LE:t>, <IntradayNPARecord: DRV_248_LE:req_SDC223_1611329111171109:2017/12/01>), (<AssetClassRestriction: DRV_248_LE:e>, <IntradayNPARecord: DRV_248_LE:req_SDC223_1611329111171109:2017/12/01>), (<AssetClassRestriction: DRV_248_LE:c>, <IntradayNPARecord: DRV_248_LE:req_SDC223_1611329111171109:2017/12/01>), (<AssetClassRestriction: DRV_248_LE:I>, <IntradayNPARecord: DRV_248_LE:req_SDC223_1611329111171109:2017/12/01>)]
util.id is 150
ac.category is r
util.limit is [[14691, 999999999999999.0, 4819920.0]]
```

since the number of elements of the list is 5, I expect the lines 3,4,5 output will repeat 5 times. However, it seemed the loop only went through one element.

Comment: Can you please share the definition of npa_util in your code?

Comment: Updated with definition of npa_util. It is basically a list of tuples. the print statement before the loop shows it has 5 elements

Comment: Are you sure you don't have e.g. a `break` somewhere in there? Is `npa_util` initialized within that function? (If it's a global, and you're running with a threaded server, other requests could be modifying it.)

Answer (score 0):

The myth has been busted: it was caused by a return statement deep in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what ac_restriction is but try the fowlloing:

npa_util =[]
for ac in ac_restriction:
npa_util.append((ac, IntradayNPARecord.objects.get(category=ac.category))